# Why are rest parameters undefined in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, babeljs

I have a React Native app that I'm programming with TypeScript (3.6.3). I have the following code (the actual code is from an API library but this is a minimum reproducable example):

```
class Base{
    someVal: string[];
    constructor() {
        this.someVal = [];
    }
    someMethod<T extends Base>(this: T, ...someArgs:string[]){
        debugger;
        this.someVal = someArgs;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{

}

let myVar = new Derived().someMethod('hello');
```

The code exactly mimics the library code, and behaves the same (erroneous) way. There are no compiler errors or warnings. When I run the code, I expect `someArgs` to be `['hello']`, but it is `undefined`. Also, I've got an `arguments` array which contains the actual value of `['hello']`:

[image]

At this point the code (which is transpiled by Babel on the fly) is acting like Javascript (hence, the undefined actual variable and the phantom arguments variable). Why isn't it transpiled correctly and how do I fix it? (I'm on Babel core/runtime 7.6.2)

Here's the relevant code from the generated `index.bundle`:

```
    var Base = function () {
    function Base() {
      (0, _classCallCheck2.default)(this, Base);
      this.someVal = [];
    }

    (0, _createClass2.default)(Base, [{
      key: "someMethod",
      value: function someMethod() {
        debugger;

        for (var _len = arguments.length, someArgs = new Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
          someArgs[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
        }

        this.someVal = someArgs;
      }
    }]);
    return Base;
  }();

  var Derived = function (_Base) {
    (0, _inherits2.default)(Derived, _Base);

    function Derived() {
      (0, _classCallCheck2.default)(this, Derived);
      return (0, _possibleConstructorReturn2.default)(this, (0, _getPrototypeOf2.default)(Derived).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    return Derived;
  }(Base);

  var myVar = new Derived().someMethod('hello');
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on the Typescript playground.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, probably. But it's not, when transpiled with Babel.

Comment: Well what does the JavaScript look like? In the playground it looks fine (of course).

Comment: @Pointy it generated a big fat `index.bundle`, I've updated the question with the relevant part, if that's what you need.

Comment: Well it's pretty clear that the generated code is simply wrong. It's treating the `this` argument as an actual formal argument.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with TypeScript and Babel to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is indeed a Babel bug that has an open PR that isn't merged to master yet: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9714:

> The TypeScript "this parameter" is a fake parameter and should not be
>   taken into account when counting the function parameters. This patch
>   skips it by using the condition taken from the transform-typescript
>   plugin.
>
> Note: since the transform-typescript plugin is removing this kind of
>   parameter, including it before the transform-parameters plugin solves
>   the issue. This patch fixes the issue in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't it transpiled correctly and how do I fix it? (I'm on Babel core/runtime 7.6.2)

The code is transpiled "correctly" in that it will behave properly when executed, but as you've seen, it does not behave the way you are expecting when inspecting the output code with a debugger. Unfortunately, there is no easy way around this.

```
someMethod<T extends Base>(this: T, ...someArgs:string[]){
    debugger;
    this.someVal = someArgs;
}
```

becomes

```
value: function someMethod() {
  debugger;

  for (var _len = arguments.length, someArgs = new Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
    someArgs[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
  }

  this.someVal = someArgs;
}
```

because Babel delays generating the `someArgs` array until latest moment before the array is used (in this case when it is assigned). In this case, that ends up being `after` your `debugger` statement. It does this because there may be branches in the function that never actual use `someArgs` and converting `arguments` into an array would be a waste of performance if the array was never used.

If you step in the debugger until you get to the `this.someVal = someArgs;` line, you'll see that `someArgs` has the value you are expecting.

Comment: Nope, when I put the `debugger` after the assignment, `someArgs` becomes an empty array, which is incorrect. I tried adding a second element (`let myVar = new Derived().someMethod('hello', 'world');`) and then it becomes an array with one element, `world`. it seems to omit the first element that I pass.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Ah sorry, this answers "Why are rest parameters undefined in TypeScript?", but I didn't even notice that you were getting the wrong number of items. The incorrect param array result ins a bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8840

Comment: Yup, I've simultaneously just found https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9714 too, covering the same issue. I've just "worked around" the issue by passing an empty `{ }` object to my function as the first parameter, which worked for my case.