# React Native TypeScript WebSocket onerror Value of "this" must be of type Event

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, websocket

I'm trying to implement WebSocket support into my app by following React Native's own tutorial at https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#websocket-support.

Here is my code:

```
function initializeSocket(socket:WebSocket){
    socket.onopen = () => {
        store.dispatch(toggleWebsocketConnected(true));
    };
    socket.onclose = () => {
        store.dispatch(toggleWebsocketConnected(false));
    };
    socket.onerror = (e:any) => {
        console.log('websocket error', e);
        store.dispatch(toggleWebsocketConnected(false));
    };
    socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        processMessage(e);
    };
}
```

In `onerror` event handler (for now, ignore why error handler is called, this is not a "why can't I connect" question, but a TypeScript question) when it's triggered I'm getting a weird error at runtime:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this" must be of type Event
    at new NodeError (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/errors.js:371:5)
    at Event.[nodejs.util.inspect.custom] (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/event_target.js:120:13)
    at formatValue (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/util/inspect.js:763:19)
    at inspect (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/util/inspect.js:340:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/util/inspect.js:2006:40)
    at formatWithOptions (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/util/inspect.js:1888:10)
    at console.value (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/console/constructor.js:323:14)
    at console.log (/path/to/my/project/lib/internal/console/constructor.js:359:61)
    at EventTarget.socket.onerror (/path/to/my/project/src/services/myproject/socket.ts:27:17)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (/path/to/my/project/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:31193:27) {code: 'ERR_INVALID_THIS', stack: 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this"…/myproject/.vscode/.react/index.bundle:31193:27)', message: 'Value of "this" must be of type Event', toString: ƒ, Symbol(kIsNodeError): true}
```

Vscode linter shows everything is fine though. When I hover over the `onerror` function it shows:

`(property) WebSocket.onerror: ((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null`

Two input arguments. So eventhough Vscode isn't complaining about my initial code, I also tried to change it to the following:

```
 socket.onerror = (_:any, e:any) => {
    console.log('websocket error', e);
    store.dispatch(toggleWebsocketConnected(false));
 };
```

Now, Vscode linter shows an error:

```
Type '(_: any, e: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any'.ts(2322)
```

If I run the code regardless of the error, I don't get a runtime error, yet `_` is now an actual event object and `e` is undefined:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct form of doing it? I've stumbled upon a weird problem with `this` keyword in arguments and TypeScript before (see [Why are rest parameters undefined in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731344/why-are-rest-parameters-undefined-in-typescript)) which indeed turned to be a Babel bug, which is now merged and fixed long ago.

How can I get it to work correectly?

<strike>**UPDATE:** I've managed to "work around" by turning the arrow function into a function with a function keyword:</strike>

```
    socket.onerror = function(this:any, e:Event){
        console.log('websocket error', e);
        store.dispatch(toggleWebsocketConnected(false));
    };
```

It "works" now, though this is not an actual solution as I still can't use arrow functions, breaking my code style as I never use `function keyword` functions in code (other than top-level simple definitions) anywhere in the app.

No it doesn't, it seemed to *step* correctly yet actually threw an error again when I reached a line to `console.log` the event.

Comment: I think you are getting an error because you are not using an arrow function so you are not binding the `this` keyword to the correct context/scope.

Try to use:

`socket.onerror = (e: Event) => { ... }`

`this` in arrow functions will be correctly bound to the scope of that function while in functions will try to "see" who's calling until eventually reaches the `window` or `global`.

Comment: @joaomlap isn't it already what I first tried (the first code snippet, `onerror`)? what is the difference?

Comment: try using `socket.addEventListener('error', cb)`

Answer (score 0):

### Example of errors

```
var wsWrong = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path')

wsWrong.onerror = (
    ev // (parameter) e: Event
) => {
```

Firstly, `wsWrong.onerror` has type:

> (property) WebSocket.onerror: ((this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any) | null

And we can see the typeof `this` in the arrow function would be

> this: typeof globalThis
>
> The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.(7041)

```
  this
```

Also,
`An arrow function cannot have a 'this' parameter.(2730)`
so that we can' t assign this type to arrow function.
we need to use a `function` to fit TypeScript's need.

Secondly,
Because event type does not have a message property,
the following will trigger an error:
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Event'.(2339)
[MDN: Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

```
  console.log(ev.message)
}
```

### To fix it, example of correct way

```
var wsRight = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path')
```

The follow line use a function here and TypeScript will resolve `this` for you. i.e. 1 argument needed.

```
wsRight.onerror = function(ev) {
```

We use [`instanceof Narrowing`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing) here
[MDN: ErrorEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent)

```
  if(ev instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    console.log(ev.message) // and now TS can found the `message` property.
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIFEA8EMFsAOAbApuA9gM3KgTnhngM7DABuse4A7sQOqEB2A5uALzhOo3j2oAjAMoYAxgGtUAFwAUAcjoAuMAAsMxKQDpRGeCESwpKuQEoydRhlaar+QtU4zg4F7nLgw4GQbwJp+E1xFKHJUJilgQPYAPnAAb2cPCAAxAEsSKWQATwAaWgZmFhtuAiJwFVhicCksxFRFRM8Xb0I6vBrA-mExSS1bUrxgmRkjVOJgrpEJaTzUcmDIUPCo2NgmLMCAHy4AV2RkRpBD8ABBJgATWnRRNfBiVHQjR9rUbGqVMfBUpnf0KkJeFgdkxRFJUlZaBg9pcBKhjqNxtUXm8WMgMAJYMgACofUguJrgHHXKxSWDfb5sf4YQHA0Hgn43RBSHZ4VBVJ7gVHozHgSjIHboN5yBFyTQyADsAAYACwARjMLgRZGOJ2QxAwOWOpx+VJpILBEJuTCYGCk5VgoXAsHAwtxcnAPj8UnwYoATOKAMyShVJO4Yd6GK7gI32s2VYipFg-BFIurVf268BA-X0440dDcVCXKT+nb3K3gAAGybpVkL8aTqTNWJeQlEeFSTLkVUz5zI+IgQlQOgu2U1HdcACFu7A8+g5mEzTU4+cMGyuKbzZbrfA2cRYCx0IhWvgav3fYqVOgsBh9tSKbRUvtqg2WJvqLc7EQGgOXAAFHftLI21fEdeb+1Z3nE0zVQaAxjNCFp3QORFknUUZFdD0PQATh9TwAG0AFkABEADkFiWKQAF0ZBUKQpEQcYwHOCc0TaTR4AwAAvK9kFgGw8BYEAwgAWgAVSEEBZ1EYgQC6EATjfABJEA4OWRIe3VNBNDRFgZDmRi1w3VAzAAXzITxeOM0QdikYzeMMiAsX9LBUmgL4pFmOAkDQTAcB0AhuzNGhYCyBpKGoOgACVI3IjguB4PhBCmXp5CUVR1C0HQ9AMIxTHMYhQpYcjiifBwk1pA0mA08hAjiX0AB5ePAfj82tEtivKfA-guQla3rRsfLY8BWWUy1CwRcsT2oLIoU0L5NFQCbZStLidlXcJIqzLNNGOfhwDHcAMMLb4NDWURXhwPDdQpQtSPIyjqJAGhbs0aDiE6pl2OsIhuJEsSKguAQMAwcQQFdEAmFO6xyPgZAAGI9tJEEjt44HShoClAiPVljmw-CFgGeSSLIiiqOUYS6IwBimNY-YOLenimAEoSPvEwRJJkuTsaIn1UiwUqviYfbYbeSBWcncrEhcJTT2mtTSq0v8dMCTw1kuE1eCxIRg1uE9gWzI8i1-f9UHLbcSd3LI1pcAyDKAA)